# Copiar todos los archivos e directorios hacia un destino en Php

Tags: php

Necesito copiar una ruta hacia otra ruta, teniendo en cuenta todos los archivos y directorios que este en la primera ruta, similar al comando `xcopy`

Solo conozco la función `copy`, existe alguna función en `PHP` que lo haga recursivamente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la documentación de `PHP` proponen la siguiente función recursiva usando [copy()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.copy.php) para mover directorios, puedes probarla para ver si te sirve.

```
<?php 
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Probado bajo XAMP windows10: Funciona perfectamente, copia vínculos y archivos con ñ

Answer (score 1):

Con la respuesta de @Juan Pinzón he modificado la función para que tenga en cuenta si debe sobrescribir el recurso si en el destino hay un recurso con el mismo nombre.

```
function xcopy($src,$dst,$rwrite=false) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    if (!file_exists($dst)) mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                xcopy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file,$rwrite); 
            } 
            else { 
                if ($rwrite) copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
}
```

Por defecto no sobrescribirá los recursos, para permitir la sobre-escritura del recurso usar `xcopy('origen','destino',true);`

Comment: Excelente modificación!!!